# Can I fly NYC Hudson River SFRA without ADS-B?

Tags: ads-b

My Canadian PA28 doesn't have ADS-B. If I fly around and below A/B/C airspace, can I fly the NYC Hudson River SFRA? Or must I fill the ADAPT authorization form?

Comment: Good news, no A airspace near NYC that you'll have to worry about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that your aircraft is certificated with an electrical system, no, you cannot fly the Hudson River SFRA unless you have either an approved ADS-B installation or a waiver/authorization from the ADAPT site.

[14 CFR 91.225(d):](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91/subpart-C/section-91.225#p-91.225(d))

> After January 1, 2020, [...] *unless otherwise authorized by ATC*, no person may operate an aircraft in the following airspace unless the aircraft has equipment installed that meets the requirements in paragraph (b) of this section:
> **(d)** Except as provided for in paragraph (e) of this section, within 30 nautical miles of an airport listed in appendix D, section 1 to this part from the surface upward to 10,000 feet MSL;

Appendix D, section 1 is the list of "Mode C veil" airports, and includes the three NYC-area Class B airports. The Hudson River SFRA is obviously well within that 30-mile area.

The exception from above is 14 CFR 91.225(e):

> The requirements of paragraph (b) of this section do not apply to any aircraft that was not originally certificated with an electrical system, or that has not subsequently been certified with such a system installed, including balloons and gliders. These aircraft may conduct operations without ADS–B Out in the airspace specified in paragraphs (d)(2) and (d)(4) of this section.

(If you are exercising the privilege allowed by paragraph (e) you must remain outside of Class B/C airspace, *and* below the ceiling altitude of the B/C airspace, or below 10,000', whichever is lower.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's what I feared, even if 14 CFR 93.350 calls it a Class B airspace EXCLUSION. Also, the FAA kneeboard" publication specifies that the skyline route (1300'+) is Class B, but doesn't say for the Hudson Exclusion (-1300').

Comment: The Class B exclusion is truly a Class B exclusion. That airspace is Class G from the surface up to but not including 700' AGL, and then Class E up to but not including 1300' MSL. But that doesn't matter for your question—the airspace is still within the 30-NM Mode C veil and therefore ADS-B Out is required from the surface up to 10k MSL. (And also required in the Class E airspace at-and-above 10k MSL, regardless of the Mode C veil.)